# How can i create vertical side heading table in tcpdf

Tags: php, tcpdf

when i use this method, the heading of table is horizontal, not the vertical heading.

```
  $link= mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db);


   if (isset($_GET['eid']))
   {
  $eid=$_GET['eid'];
   }



  $output = '';  
  $count=0;
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM event_record where eventID='{$eid}' ";  
  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {       
      $count++;
  $output .= "<tr>  
                      <td>$count</td>
                      <td>{$row['studentID']}</td>  
                      <td>{$row['studentName']}</td>  
                      <td>{$row['contact']}</td>  
                      <td>{$row['program']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['booking_date']}</td>
                      <td>{$row['booking_type']}</td>  
                 </tr>  
                      ";  

  }  

  return $output;
```

i want the result of the pdf is , the table heading is at the vertical and at the left side, not horizontal.

```
 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="3%">No.</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Student ID</th> 
                           <th width="10%">Student Name</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Contact</th>  
                           <th width="5%">Program</th>  
                           <th width="8%">Booking Date</th>
                           <th width="10%">Booking Type</th>  
                      </tr>  
                 <?php  
                 echo fetch_data();  
                 ?>  
                 </table>
```

Below code is merge the value and the table heading

```
  <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">  
       <tr>  
            <th width="5%">No.</th>  
            <th width="15%">Student ID</th> 
            <th width="20%">Student Name</th>  
            <th width="15%">Contact</th>  
            <th width="10%">Program</th>  
            <th width="15%">Booking Date</th>
            <th width="15%">Booking Type</th>  
       </tr>  
  ';  
  $content .= fetch_data();  
  $content .= '</table>';  
  $obj_pdf->writeHTML($content);  
  $obj_pdf->Output('file.pdf', 'I');
```

[I need a result like this,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrRW2.png)

Comment: Could you also show us the code that is being used to generate the PDF? Also, you need to also describe better what you mean by it is not working in your code.

Comment: okok, i already change my code, and try to make it more clear